Why $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}y+\cdots+y^{p-1}\neq p$ for all integer $p,x,y>2$? ($p$ is a prime)
Why $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}y+\cdots+y^{p-1}\neq p$ for all integer $p,x,y>2$ where $p$ is a prime?
The answer is not evident to me. I tried Fermat's little theorem to no avail. Any hints?
First, I assume $x-y$ is not divisible by $p$.
Hence,
$$x^p-y^p\equiv (x-y)\pmod p$$
Then
$$\frac{x^p-y^p}{x-y}\equiv 1 \pmod p\ne p$$
That takes care of one case.
If $x\equiv y\pmod p$, then I am not sure how to proceed.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I changed $n$ for $p$.
ORIGINAL QUESTION:
$$(x+y)(x^{p-1} - x^{p-2}y + x^{p-3}y^2 + \cdots -xy^{p-2} + y^{p-1})$$ $$= (x+y)\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} (-1)^iy^ix^{p-i-1} \ = \ (x+y)\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} (-1)^ix^iy^{p-i-1}$$
$$= x^p+y^p.$$
However, assuming WLOG that $x \ge y$ note the following:  $\frac{x^p+y^p}{x+y} \ge \frac{x^{p-1}}{2} >> p$. Thus from this
$\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} (-1)^iy^ix^{p-i-1}$ is simply much larger than $p$ [as long as one of $|x|,|y|,p$ is at least $4$, each of the cases when all of $|x|,|y|,p \le 3$ can easily be checked directly] so it cannot be $p$. To sum up, $\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} (-1)^iy^ix^{p-i-1}$ is not $p$ for any integers $x,y \ge 2$ and any positive integer $p$. This answers the original question and does not require $p$ to be prime.
This certainly  holds as well for the revised easier question, as
$$\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}x^iy^{p-i-1} \ge \sum_{i=0}^{p-1}(-1)^ix^iy^{p-i-1}.$$

The answer to the revised question is trivial: Since there are $p$ positive terms greater than 1 in that expression, then it is greater than to $p$. $\square$
